# Integrate $\int _0^{\infty }\:\:\frac{6}{\theta}xe^{-\frac{2x}{\theta }}\left(1-e^{-\frac{x}{\theta }}\right)dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

Need help integrating:
$$\int _0^{\infty }\:\:\frac{6}{\theta}xe^{-\frac{2x}{\theta }}\left(1-e^{-\frac{x}{\theta }}\right)dx$$

I think I should multiply the $$xe^{-\frac{2x}{\theta }}$$ out and then use integration by parts but it is not really working for me?

Comment: check what is "integration by parts"

Answer (score 2):

Integrate by parts as follows

\begin{align}
& \int _0^{\infty }\:\:\frac{6}{\theta}xe^{-\frac{2x}{\theta }}\left(1-e^{-\frac{x}{\theta }}\right)dx\\
=& \frac6{\theta} \int _0^{\infty }
x\> d \left( -\frac {\theta}2 e^{-\frac{2x}{\theta } }
 + \frac {\theta}3e^{-\frac{3x}{\theta } } \right)
= \int _0^{\infty }
\left( 3e^{-\frac{2x}{\theta } }
 -2 e^{-\frac{3x}{\theta } } \right)dx
= \frac 56{\theta}
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

Hint.

Abstractly, all you need is to find integrals of the form:
$$
\int xe^{mx}dx
$$
which by a change of variables, you only need to find
$$
\int xe^{mx}dx
=\frac{1}{m^2}\int ue^udu=
\frac{1}{m^2}\int xe^{x}dx=\frac{1}{m^2}(xe^x-e^x)+C
$$

---

The integrand in your integral is
$$
xe^{\frac{-2}{\theta}\cdot x}-xe^{\frac{-3}{\theta}\cdot x}
$$
each term is of the form $xe^{mx}$ for some $m$.

Comment: because each single integral converges on $[0, \infty)$, provided that $\theta$ is positive

Answer (score 0):

$$I=\int_0^{\infty } \frac{6 x}{t} e^{-\frac{2 x}{t}} \left(1-e^{-\frac{x}{t}}\right) \, dx$$
Set $$e^{-\frac{x}{t}}=u\to x=-t\log u;\;dx=-\frac{t}{u}$$
$$I=\int_1^0-6 (1-u) u^2 \log u\left(-\frac{t}{u}\right)\,du=$$
$$=6t\int_0^1 (u-1) u \log u\,du=6t[-\frac{u^3}{9}+\frac{1}{3} u^3 \log u+\frac{u^2}{4}-\frac{1}{2} u^2 \log u]_0^1=\frac{5 }{6}t$$
As $$\underset{u\to 0}{\text{lim}}\left(-\frac{u^3}{9}+\frac{1}{3} u^3 \log u+\frac{u^2}{4}-\frac{1}{2} u^2 \log u\right)=0$$

TL;DR $I=\frac{5 }{6}t$